# Large taxonomy (2000+ terms), causing WordPress to hang

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a large taxonomy (and about to grow a lot larger) with several thousand terms in it. When I'm editing a post, there is now a significant hang when it goes to load the term list.

Has anyone run into this before? Any suggestions for dealing with such a large list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is probably because your taxonomy is hierarchical, and the default meta box for such taxonomies is similar to the category box - which displays all terms as input elements. So the browser lag for thousands of elements within a page is expected in this case.

If you can't make your taxonomy non-hierarchical, try [removing the default meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) and [create your own](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), in which you display only the most used terms, a single input field with autocomplete or something similar

Comment: Yes, it is hierarchical. Autocomplete is a good idea.. Thank you for that! I'll get to work on it.